# Pending intent always make new activity

Tags: java, android, nfc

i trying to make app with nfc function. the problem is when nfc tag discovered, pending intent always make a new activity that already exist. i'm using tab host.
how to make pendingintent without making a new activity.
thanks a lot.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);        

            mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);                              
            mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this,
    getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }

    protected void onResume() {    
            super.onResume();
            mResumed = true;               
            // Sticky notes received from Android
            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {            
                NdefMessage[] messages = getNdefMessages(getIntent());
                byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();            
                try     { cekNfc(new String(payload)); }
                catch (SQLException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); } 
                catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)      {  e.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)  { e.printStackTrace(); }

                setIntent(new Intent());
            }
            enableNdefExchangeMode();        
        }   
        private void enableNdefExchangeMode() { mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcPendingIntent, mNdefExchangeFilters, null); } 

    NdefMessage[] getNdefMessages(Intent intent) {  // Parse the intent             
            NdefMessage[] msgs = null;        
            String action = intent.getAction();
            //jika ada action
            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {                      
                Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
                if (rawMsgs != null) {
                    msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {  msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i]; }
                }
            } 
            return msgs;
        }


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);        

            mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);                              
            mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this,
    getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }

    protected void onResume() {    
            super.onResume();
            mResumed = true;               
            // Sticky notes received from Android
            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {            
                NdefMessage[] messages = getNdefMessages(getIntent());
                byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();            
                try     { cekNfc(new String(payload)); }
                catch (SQLException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); } 
                catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)      {  e.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)  { e.printStackTrace(); }

                setIntent(new Intent());
            }
            enableNdefExchangeMode();        
        }   
        private void enableNdefExchangeMode() { mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcPendingIntent, mNdefExchangeFilters, null); } 

    NdefMessage[] getNdefMessages(Intent intent) {  // Parse the intent             
            NdefMessage[] msgs = null;        
            String action = intent.getAction();
            //jika ada action
            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {                      
                Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
                if (rawMsgs != null) {
                    msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {  msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i]; }
                }
            } 
            return msgs;
        }
```

Answer (score 11):

Put `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for your activity (or activities) in the manifest. That does the trick. Whenever an NFC intent is dispatched by the system, always a new Activity will be created. This is unique for NFC intents. So setting `android:launchMode="singleTop"` will not work, nor will setting flags in the PendingIntent.

Another solution is to use [NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableForegroundDispatch%28android.app.Activity,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.content.IntentFilter[],%20java.lang.String[][]%29) in all your Activities. That way your app gets to handle all NFC intents itself directly (via `onNewIntent()`).

Comment: i tried android:launchMode="singleTask" but still, doesn't work and did use NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch() but doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: How did you define `mNdefExchangeFilters`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: what is their value.

Comment: Is "nothing" an empty list or `null`? A value of `null` would act a s a wildcard, matching everything. I am not sure what the result of an empty list is. May be it results in not matching anything, so it would bypass the foreground dispatch as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
mNotificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

And in your manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: `android:launchMode="singleTask"` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Create your pending intent as below:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this,
    getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
    |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
    |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), 0);
```

Comment: did you also try setting `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to your activity in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the flag "PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT" while calling the "getActivity" method. I2m using it without a problem.

Comment: i'm assuming that you put the flag in Intent.addFlag from what i see from your code and the other answers. it should be put instead of the last flag "0" in PendingIntent.getActivity

Comment: one more suggestion. try "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" in the Intent.addFlags method this time when creating the intent.

Comment: ok, it is not related to creation of pending intent if you use enableForegroundDispatch and onNewIntent is called. I don't know much about NFC but i will probably be using it soon at work; so i'm interested.
can you tell me why you use setIntent(new Intent())

Comment: i don't know,  i get that from android nfc example. i don't really understand about nfc, i'm new a this.

Comment: i asked because i haven't seen it so far in other posts on stackoverflow. I don't know the details, but try calling enableForegroundDispatch in the first call of this activity (maybe in onCreate). if this method is not called, then the onNewIntent method is not called so onResume is not called.

Comment: is it possible there are a problem in my intent filter??

Answer (score 0):

use this flag instead..

```
new Intent(this,
    getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but not using a TabHost - every time an NFC tag was scanned my app was launching a new activity rather than firing `onNewIntent` as I wanted. I was trying to set `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the manifest and use  `NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()` in my activities `onResume` method. Instead, I abandoned using PendingIntent and set up intent filters my activity in the manifest as follows:

```
    <activity
        ...
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.myname.myapp" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
```