# Pending intent force-create new activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Not a duplicate of: [Pending intent always make new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104110/pending-intent-always-make-new-activity) since no solution is there.

Here is my PendingIntent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);       
return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_PUSH_MESSAGE_TYPE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

If I close the app (e.g. back button) and use this PendingIntent in the notification it will create a new activity.

If however I pause the app (e.g. home button) and click on the same notification the activity (and the containing fragment) will be resumed.

How can I create a new activity (and its fragment) everytime I use this PendingIntent?

Answer (score 1):

use the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

From the documentation

> If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this
>   history stack.

you can add in `or`, with the other flags you are using

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: it still creates a new activity instance above current one

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` from the `Intent`. The use of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` tells Android to reuse the existing instance of the Activity.